# "Invalid JSON primitive: geometry" when adding features

Tags: python, arcgis-rest-api, json

I'm trying to use the arcGIS Rest API to add features to a feature layer, but I get an "Invalid JSON primitive: geometry" error.  I get the same results if I leave out the spatialReference.

The feature layer was created on the arcGIS Developer Site, setting the geometry type to "Points". The fields are store_id (integer), address (string), items (string), and item_desc (string).

What am I doing wrong?

**Python 2.7 code**

```
import requests

def test_upload(token):
    test_locations = [
        {
            'store_id': 79,
            'address': 'address1',
            'latitude': 48.4680466419,
            'longitude': -94.4650303558,
            'item_id': '2 3 1',
            'desc': 'bar, baz, foo'
        },
        {
            'store_id': 89,
            'address': 'address2',
            'latitude': 48.7006190216,
            'longitude': -115.9411092720,
            'item_id': '2',
            'desc': 'bar'
        },
        {
            'store_id': 161,
            'address': 'address3',
            'latitude': 48.7425504958,
            'longitude': -111.5460764360,
            'item_id': '3 1',
            'desc': 'baz, foo'
        }
    ]

    features = []
    for location in test_locations:
        feature = {
            'attributes': {
                'store_id': location['store_id'],
                'address': location['address'],
                'items': location['item_id'],
                'item_desc': location['desc']
            },
            'geometry': {
                'x': location['longitude'],
                'y': location['latitude'],
                'spatialReference': {'wkid': 4326}
            }
        }
        features.append(feature)
    data = {
        'f': 'json',
        'features': features,
        'rollbackOnFailure': False,
        'token': token
    }

    print '############'
    print 'The JSON request looks like:'
    printable_data = data.copy()
    printable_data['token'] = '<withheld>'
    print json.dumps(printable_data, indent=2, separators=(',', ': '))
    print
    print '############'

    resp = requests.post(FEATURE_URL + '/addFeatures', data=data)
    print 'The response from the server is:'
    print 'HTTP Status Code:', resp.status_code
    print json.dumps(resp.json(), indent=2, separators=(',', ': '))
```

**Output**
When FEATURE_URL is defined and test_upload is passed a valid token, this gives the following output:

```
############
The JSON request looks like:
{
  "rollbackOnFailure": false,
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "y": 48.4680466419,
        "x": -94.4650303558,
        "spatialReference": {
          "wkid": 4326
        }
      },
      "attributes": {
        "items": "2 3 1",
        "item_desc": "bar, baz, foo",
        "store_id": 79,
        "address": "address1"
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "y": 48.7006190216,
        "x": -115.941109272,
        "spatialReference": {
          "wkid": 4326
        }
      },
      "attributes": {
        "items": "2",
        "item_desc": "bar",
        "store_id": 89,
        "address": "address2"
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "y": 48.7425504958,
        "x": -111.546076436,
        "spatialReference": {
          "wkid": 4326
        }
      },
      "attributes": {
        "items": "3 1",
        "item_desc": "baz, foo",
        "store_id": 161,
        "address": "address3"
      }
    }
  ],
  "token": "<withheld>",
  "f": "json"
}

############
The response from the server is:
HTTP Status Code: 200
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Cannot perform operation. Invalid operation parameters.",
    "code": 400,
    "details": [
      "'features' parameter is invalid",
      "Invalid JSON primitive: geometry."
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using an HTTP monitoring tool such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to verify the requests are being passed correctly? What happens when you do a `json.dumps` on your data when you pass it into the post request?  `resp = requests.post(FEATURE_URL + '/addFeatures', json.dumps(data))`

Comment: Changing `data=data` to `json.dumps(data)` doesn't seem to pass the request correctly. I get back an HTML (not JSON) response that includes `<div class="restErrors">Token Required<br/></div>`. I'll look into Fiddler.

Comment: That's interesting as you are clearly passing in a token.  Maybe try it on this line: `'features': json.dumps(features)`.  Other than that, your code looks like it should be working to me.  But yes, definitely download Fiddler and open it while you run this code.  Inside the `Inspectors` tab, when you click on the `WebForms` tab it will show all the parameters you passed in your query.  This is by far the best tool I have found for debugging python requests against REST Endpoints.

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution to this?  I am experiencing the same thing.

Comment: @traggatmot I never did, but I stopped looking long ago. An answer may be out there.

Comment: I figured out a workable solution for updating features where I was getting the same error. Let me know if you'd like me to post.

Comment: Great news! I don't need it anymore, but it might help somebody in the future if you feel like posting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to the list getting lost using resp.url would probably come back with something like
   ...&updates=geometry&updates=attributes&f=json....

Therefore json.dumps is the answer  but you want to do it to the features list not to the data.

```
data = {
    'f': 'json',
    'features': json.dumps(features),
    'rollbackOnFailure': False,
    'token': token
}
```